# how to set a python function in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code:

```
a= {'u':exec("def u(str):return Unicode(str,'utf-8')"),}
print a
```

but it show error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/桌面/test$ python a.py
  File "a.py", line 5
    a= {'u':exec("def u(str):return Unicode(str,'utf-8')"),}
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i wiil stored it to my company's database , it must be a dict ,

what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: I would suggest not using "str" as your variable argument as this is already a well defined function in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives would be to store the function instead, or the code as text:

```
a= {'u': lambda x: Unicode(x,'utf-8')}
```

or

```
a= {'u':"def u(str):return Unicode(str,'utf-8')",}
```

and then execute it as

```
exec(a['u'])
```

Comment: may be should not has the `return` in the lambda

Answer (score 0):

`exec` does not return a value; instead, it evaluates some code in the current context (by default) or a user-specified context. By "context", I mean the locals and globals dicts.

It looks like you want the following:

```
a = {  }
exec "def u(string): return unicode(string, 'utf-8')" in { }, a
# a now contains method by name 'u', just like your original example
a['u']('cheese')    # -> u'cheese'
```

This works by executing the code string with a temporary dict (`{  }`) to store the generated globals, and `a` to store the locals. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) for more info.

You can use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) if you need to evaluate the *value* of a code block (though you cannot `eval()` a method declaration).

Note also that `unicode` should have a lower-case U.

Comment: "though you cannot eval() a method declaration", are you sure, I just tried it and it worked... exec("def t(x): return x**x") and then t(5) returned 3125.

Comment: oh wait, I see what I did; I evaled a function declaration and it well... declared a function, doh.

Comment: @Andrew: You `exec`ed it, not `eval()`ed it :-)

Comment: well poo I forgot there was an eval and a exec in Python, I need to go to bed :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much of an answer this is but it *seems* to work if you pull out the exec to a function param first...

```
>>> exec("def t(x): return x**x")
>>> t(5)
3125
>>> a={'t': t}
>>> a['t'](5)
3125
```

Now that I've had a chance to think about this it makes sense. Exec will evaluate a block of code but it doesn't return anything. My code snip above declares a function *t* which can be assigned to a dict.